# Laravel API JSON

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I'm new here. I'm trying to make a Laravel API to display a dropdown, the dropdown is something like this:
[Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onrp1.png)

The JSON data format is like this:

```
{
    "Ford": {
        "Focus": ["1.6 TDCI", "1.8 TDCI", "RS"],
        "Fiesta": ["1.2 TDCI", "1.4 TDCI", "Fiesta RS"]
    },
    "BMW": {
        "Serie 1": ["2.0 TDI", "3.0 TURBO", "SPORT"],
        "Serie 3": ["320D", "360I"]
    },
    "Audi": {
        "RS": ["RS1", "RS2", "RS3", "RS4"],
        "RS2": ["RS66", "RS75"]
    }
}
```

In the database I have a single table from where I have to fetch the data, is called 'cars'. In that table I have 'make', 'model' and 'body_type' as in the follow screenshot: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJqMI.png)

I'm able to get all the content but I don't know how to sort it to get the data as I need it (^as in the dumb json example listed above...

In my web.php I have:

```
Route::get('test', 'api@cars');
```

In my api controller @cars I have:

```
public function cars() {
  $req = cars::all();
  return $req;
}
```

And the current output that I get is this: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpYE9.png)

Comment: @DaveCarruthers, is not that the problem, the thing is that I have multiple multiple body_types, multiple models & multiple makes, and I want to get the same result as in the dumb JSON (that I included here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like this ?

```
$req = cars::all();
$json = [];
foreach ($req as $car){
  $json[$car->make][$car->model][]=$car->body_type;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! 
I learned something new today, basically what I did it was something like this in my cars model: [here](https://pastebin.com/TtRX2J3z) 
It took me almost 40 lines of code, and you did everything in 5 lines.